# sellerid is getting erroneously passed to other functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

```
const productIds = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', ...]

const generateBearerToken = async () => {
    await //api calling
    } // will return bearerToken

const getSubmissions = async () => {
    await // api calling
    }

let sellerId = null
const getPublisherId = async (productId) => {
    //generating bearer token using generateBearerToken() 
    await GenerateBearerToken()
    //calling API here and setting the value of sellerId
    const response = await axios.get(url, { header })
    //From this response, I am setting the value of sellerId, then calling getSubmission()
    sellerId = response.data.sellerId
    await getSubmission()
}

productsIds.map((productId) => {
    await getPublisherId(productId)
})
```

The `sellerId` which I am getting from `getPublisherId`, I am using that value in the header for calling `getSubmissions`. This value (`sellerId`) is different for different product Ids. But when I am calling this above map function, the `sellerId` of one is getting passed in other calling `getSubmissions`, that should be not the case. The `sellerId` should be passed to that particular `getSubmissions` only. How to avoid this collision?

Comment: Why is `sellerId` global?  Why not declare it within the only function that uses it?  (What is it even used for?  It's assigned but never read.)

Comment: sellerId we are getting from getPublisherId and then using this value inside getSubmissions(). So this variable should be global

Comment: You should pass it as a parameter instead, makes it much easier to see when it changes

Comment: My suggestion is to modify your code to avoid that global variable, why not pass the sellerId as a param to the getSubmissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be global:

```
let sellerId = null
```

Every asynchronous operation is modifying that value, and any other operation will use whatever the value is *at that time*, not whatever it *was* when that operation may have been invoked.

Don't use global variables to pass values from one function to another.  Just pass the value to the function:

```
const getSubmissions = async (sellerId) => {
  //...
};
```

and:

```
const getPublisherId = async (productId) => {
    await GenerateBearerToken();
    const response = await axios.get(url, { header });
    await getSubmissions(response.data.sellerId);
};
```

As an aside, the code *suggests* that you're making the same mistake elsewhere and this same thing may need to be corrected in other places.

Answer (score 1):

- avoid globals
- you are using .map as a "for each". Map is made to transform data.

At a minimum you want:

```
/* let sellerId = null  // < Remove global */
const getPublisherId = async (productId) => {
   [...]
   const sellerId = response.data.sellerId
   await getSubmission()
   return sellerId
}

const allSellerIds = productsIds.map((productId) => {
    await getPublisherId(productId)
})
```

However you will probably want to look up Promise.allSettled and others to avoid each publisher from being fetched one at a time sequentially.